# Who are some of the Koha-Ace characters in the ED?

Tags: carnival-phantasm

During the ED of the *Carnival Phantasm Special Season* OVA, we see just about [all of the cast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1Eki.jpg) from major Type-Moon works as *Koha-Ace* characters.

From right to left, who are the person (13th from the left, not including the floating characters) between Hisui and Miyako, the person (10th from the left, not including Keitai-san, the cellphone) between Caster (Fate/Extra) and Chikagi, and the very last person on the far left (first one from the left)?

[image: And that's everyone!]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the one on the far left is [Kariya Matou](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Kariya_Matou) from *Fate/Zero*,

[image: Dat guy]

the one next to Chikagi is [Rani VIII](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Rani_VIII) from *Fate/Extra* (it's a bit hard to see as reface is mostly obscure, but the clothing and skin color matches),

[image: Dat obscured person]

and the one in front of Miyako is [Assassin (Li Shuwen)](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Assassin_(Fate/Extra)), also from *Fate/Extra* (the wardrobe practically gives it away).

[image: Dat wardrobe]

Comment: getting all their name would also be helpful..